# ionic2: How to create an accordion which shows a list of items from a REST API on click of the accordion?

Tags: list, angular, typescript, ionic2, accordion

I want to create an accordion functionality in my ionic2 mobile app where I need to show a list of items which are not accordions unlike shown here https://github.com/mahmoudissmail/ionic2Accordion

I've seen most of the sources mention that link for accordion in ionic2. But my requirement is completely different.

I just need one accordion(not a list of accordions) which can show a list of items. I've tried modifying the code given in the above source for one accordion. But what I figured out is that the icon and the data are binded in that. For me I just need one icon. On click of that icon or the title I need to generate a list of items which I have in an array of objects that I retrieved from a REST API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad I finally got the answer after searching a lot on the internet. I don't know how come this link is not showing up, which is provided by the official ionic2 team.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/accordion-component-not-found-in-ionic-2/77576

It helped me in creating an accordion of my requirement.

Here is my code for a single accordion with a list of data:
This is my HTML file.

```
<ion-item color="danger" (click)="toggle()">
  PopularMovies
  <ion-icon item-left name="add"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of popularMovieData" [@expand]="active">{{item.name}}</ion-item>
```

And this is my .ts file

```
 import { Component,trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-search',
  templateUrl: 'search.html',
  styles:[
  `
  .item-block{
    min-height: 0;
    transition: 0.09s all linear;
  }
  `
  ],
  animations: [
    trigger('expand', [
      state('true', style({ height: '45px' })),
      state('false', style({ height: '0'})),
      transition('void => *', animate('0s')),
      transition('* <=> *', animate('250ms ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class Search {

popularMovieData:Array<any>=[];
active: boolean;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public http:Http) {
    this.navCtrl=navCtrl;
    this.navParams=navParams;
   this.active=false;
}

  getPopularMovies()
  {
    this.http.post('enter the API url',{}).subscribe(resp=>{ 
    this.popularMovieData = resp.data;
    },
    err=>{console.log(err);},
    ()=>{});
  }

   toggle() 
   {
   this.active = !this.active
  }
}
```